# Triangulation of Polyhedron fails

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation, polyhedra

I am trying to triangulate the faces of a polyhedron using CGAL 4.13 and the following code snippet, which takes a polyhedron definition file in OFF format on stdin:

```
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/triangulate_faces.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    Polyhedron p;
    cin >> p;
    if (!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(p)) 
        cerr << p << endl << "Triangulation failed!" << endl;
}
```

However, I observe the following warning:

> CGAL warning: check violation! Expression : false File       :
>   /usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_2.h Line       : 902
>   Explanation: You are using an exact number type, using a
>   Constrained_triangulation_plus_2 class would avoid cascading
>   intersection computation  and be much more efficient This message is
>   shown only if CGAL_NO_CDT_2_WARNINGis not defined.
>
> Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at
>   https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html

and the triangulation fails. The message `Triangulation failed!` is printed as well as the polyhedron definition, which clearly shows some faces with 5 or even 7 vertices.

Unfortunately the OFF representation of the polyhedron is 8070 lines long, and I failed to create a smaller example to reproduce the issue. So I uploaded it [here](https://ufile.io/h61kc). It is only available for 30 days there, if someone can suggest a better place to upload it, I will consider that.

After compiling, for example with

> g++ -O3 tri.cpp -o tri -lCGAL -lgmp -lmpfr -Wall

the issue can be reproduced with

> ./tri < poly.off

I am not sure if the failure of the triangulation is related to the warning; how could I use the `Constrained_triangulation_plus_2` class with `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces()`? Is this possible at all? Triangulation of a face is not a complicated thing, how can this fail in the first place?

Comment: See if this is relevant: http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Issues-with-Polygon-mesh-processing-triangulate-face-td4664131.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an exact kernel, you should use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`, which will silent the warning and then probably the triangulation won't fail. If you do need an exact kernel, you can use [`CGAL::copy_face_graph()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga2d3eb044bfe42eab566779ce32216c11) to easily switch from Epeck to Epick, triangulate, then switch back to Epeck.